# Trying to pass an authenticated user to DB controller in nodejs with bookshelf

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am creating a web app that first allows a user to login using credentials stored in a mysql database.
Then, when they go to  /crm I am trying to pass a field value, that specifies what database to which the user has access, through to instantiate a bookshelf/knex database connection.

crmDB.js

```
var knex= require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection:{
        host: 'localhost',  // your host
        user: 'the user', // your database user
        password: 'the password, // your database password
        database: req.user.db, // the database name per the user.db field
        charset: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'
    }
});

var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

module.exports.crmDB = Bookshelf;
```

can I do this? What do I put in my route?

```
var crm = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){


    } else {
        res.redirect('/signin');
    }
}
```

Comment: What I have done is exported user and required user in crmDB. I don't know if this is a good way to handle it, and I haven't moved on very far to know if it is working/sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in route.js

```
var crm = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        var user = req.user;
        module.exports = {
            user:user
        };
        var crmModel = require('../server/models/crm');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/signin');
    }
}
```

Then in the crmDB.js

```
var db = require('../../client/routes').user.toJSON().db;

var knex= require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection:{
       host: 'localhost',  // your host
       user: 'user', // your database user
       password: 'password', // your database password
       database: db,
       charset: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'
    }
});
```